# Regex: Find the minimal match... ? not cutting it

Tags: javascript, regex

I've read so many answers, and it is always to use the ? operator.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Given a sample string such as:

```
the beginning stuff:0:evnt:some random stuff:MISTER GREEN:more stuff:1:evnt:again random stuff:MISS SCARLET:the rest of the stuff
```

What pattern can I use to get the "1" prior to "MISS SCARLET"? Without relying on knowing what's in any of the random stuff parts.  I do know it will always be a digit followed by ":evnt" (without quotes) prior to the name we're looking for.  In my case, there's no worry about other names getting in the way (ie. it would never be something like :3:evnt:blahblahMISTER GREEN blah blah MISS SCARLET without another x:evnt in between)

I originally came up with:

```
(\d):evnt.*MISS SCARLET
```

which gives "0" because it matches back to the index for Mister Green, since .* matches everything.  Ok, so ? to the rescue:

```
(\d):evnt.*?MISS SCARLET
```

Nope, same result.

How do I get the CLOSEST match to the text in question?  I'm sure I'm not wording that correctly, but the example should show what I want.  I want to isolate that "1" with MISS SCARLET and "0" if I were looking for MISTER GREEN

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negated character class:

```bash
(\d+):evnt:[^:]*:MISS SCARLET
```

Where `[^:]*` matches 0 or more of any characters that is not `:`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xt5T6i/1)

However if there is a possibility of presence of colon after `evnt` keyword then you can use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```bash
(\d+):evnt:(?:(?!:evnt:).)*?:MISTER GREEN
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Xt5T6i/2)

Here `(?:(?!:evnt:).)*?` will make sure match 0 or more of any characters as long as `:evnt:` doesn't appear anywhere in that text.

Comment: It works for MISS SCARLET, but if I replace that with MISTER GREEN it doesn't.  I would expect a "0" result for Green and "1" for Scarlet.

Correction: Your first example works, your second doesn't

Comment: And I'm not sure the assumption required for the first example is flexible enough (I don't know if colons will exist)

Comment: @bcsteeve: Check my updated answer and `RegEx Demo 2`

Comment: That works!  I'm surprised it has to be that complicated.  It occurred to me that I'm basically looking for a normal regex pattern, but backwards.  Is there not a way to start at the MISS SCARLET and then look left for the :evnt: and then capture the \d+ to the left?

Comment: No, regex matching is always from left to right. We can do lookbehind for assertions only.

Comment: It finally occurred to me though... that I can reverse the string and then do this a lot simpler.  Your method works, don't get me wrong!!  But it succeeds in over 140 thousands steps compared to 280 by reversing the source first.  Mind you, I'm not sure how efficient it is to reverse large strings.   THANKS!

Comment: Actually my first regex is really the fastest solution in colon delimited text as shown in your examples.